# My excel export does not bring me the styles of my table

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui

I have a table where I paint cell I also have filters and I have a header with style. Now when I want to export to excel it does not do it with the style of my table, does anyone know how to do it?

In advance I thank you for the help!

Comment: Strange, it works for me...

Answer (score 0):

You can use excelExport event to manually change color of your cells.

**Example:**

```
excelExport: function(e) {
      var sheet = e.workbook.sheets[0];
      for (var rowIndex = 1; rowIndex < sheet.rows.length; rowIndex++) {
        if (rowIndex % 2 == 0) {
          var row = sheet.rows[rowIndex];
          for (var cellIndex = 0; cellIndex < row.cells.length; cellIndex ++) {
            row.cells[cellIndex].background = "#aabbcc";
          }
        }
      }
```